# How can I create a custom terminal command (to run a script)?

Tags: command-line

I'm a web developer. When I want to start working, always i'm executing some command on terminal. For example:

```
sudo service apache2 start
sudo service mysql start
sublime
```

For speed up this process, I create a `.sh` file which contain these commands.

Now, when I want to start working, I'm just executing this .sh file and all services (mysql, apache2 etc.) starting.

Is it possible to create a custom command for this? For example if I type `sudo start-working` to terminal, it will execute these commands

Answer (score 73, accepted):

A common way people handle this is to make a `bin` directory in their home directory: `mkdir ~/bin`

Then, you can put your custom scripts in there: `mv start-working ~/bin`

Make sure your script is executable: `chmod +x ~/bin/start-working`

Add this to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file (if you're using bash, which you probably are): `export PATH=$PATH:~/bin`

Now log back in and out of your terminal and you should be able to simply type `start-working`, and your script will execute.

Now that your path is setup, any new scripts you drop into your `~/bin` you can just type in the name of.

Comment: +1, and instead of logging out and in, you can simply run the `source ~/.bashrc` or `. ~/.bashrc` commands to apply the changes.

Comment: Joe Oppegaard,
I find this really useful information as there are completed scripts I have and would like run as a command rather than a script. 

Is there a way to include all subdirectories that you create in ~/bin so that you don't have to include multiple export lines in .bashrc? 

I tried `export PATH=$PATH:~/bin/*` but that didn't return the desired results.

Comment: The default `~/.profile` already adds `~/bin` to PATH, so appending it in `~/.bashrc` in addition will pointlessly add it twice or more.

Comment: It worked without me appending anything to .bashrc, so you may be able to skip that as geriha says

Comment: in my experience, when you add new file you have to redo a chmod command, otherwise the permission will be denied

Comment: `echo "export PATH=\$PATH:~/bin" >> ~/.bashrc` to add the path export. `tail -n 10 ~/.bashrc` to confirm it worked.

Comment: `mkdir ~/bin; echo "echo \"bin directory created\";date;" >> ~/bin/user_test; chmod -R +x ~/bin; echo "export PATH=\$PATH:~/bin" >> ~/.bashrc; tail -n 10 ~/.bashrc; source ~/.bashrc; user_test;` should do all of it.

Answer (score 22):

I was looking how to create custom commands and I found this question among others. I think what I was looking for was for aliases so I'll give you the way to do this with an alias.

On your home folder:

```
nano .bash_aliases
```

And there you can write down your commands in one line:

```
alias start-working='sudo service apache2 start; sudo service mysql start; sublime'
```

After saving the file reconfigure your bashrc

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

And check your new alias is loaded

```
alias
```

That's it, you can start working now by running

```
start-working
```