# Creating a terminal command to extract tarballs

Tags: command-line, bash

This is pure laziness, but I'm looking to create a custom terminal command to extract tarballs - ie "targz" then a filename would extract a tar.gz tarball, and "tarbz2"... Well, guess.
I followed the instructions for creating custom commands found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118312/creating-custom-command), and while I'm sure that worked great for that asker (who wanted a command to start a couple of things for him, which required no additional arguments or anything), it's not working for me. The "targz" file in my ~/bin reads as follows:

```
tar -xzvf
```

What wizardry. So I type

```
targz putty-0.62.tar.gz
```

in the terminal, and it gives me:

```
tar: option requires an argument -- 'f'
```

Any way to make this work so I can just type "targz" then the target filename into the terminal and have it be extracted? Or, for extra sloth points, type something like "untar" then a target filename, then have it be extracted whether it's .gz or .bz2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is pass arguments to a shell script. Check out this [link](http://www.bashguru.com/2009/11/how-to-pass-arguments-to-shell-script.html). I think you'll have your answer. As for the second part of your question, using `tar -xvf` will untar any file whether it's .gz, .bz2 or .xz.

Answer (score 4):

you could also create an alias like this:

```
alias utgz='tar -zxf '
```

Now issuing `utgz tarball.tar.gz` will extract all the files from the ta, without the overhead of going through a separate shell.
As I understand it the alias just acts as a  text substitution.

If you type alias at your prompt you might see something like `'ls=ls -F'` and so on.
so `utgz tarball.tar.gz` gets changed to `tar -zxf tarball.tar.gz`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to AskUbuntu.com. I like your answer better than the accepted one because I feel it is a little more elegant to use an alias for this than starting a separate shell, but could you rewrite your answer to make it a bit clearer for the asker?

Comment: the weakness of alias though is that it only works in the shell, while having an actual script in the PATH will work everywhere else. Though that could be a strength as well.

Comment: This situation is ideally suited for an alias. It's true that aliases only work in a shell, but I'd be quite surprised if anyone needed a simple shortcut like this anywhere except a shell.