# unable to create custom command in shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a working shell script that I would like to add as a command `mein-befehl` referring to that [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118312/how-can-i-create-a-custom-terminal-command-to-run-a-script):

```
#!/bin/bash
original_string="$1"
string_to_replace_with='7'
result_string="${original_string/6/$string_to_replace_with}"
echo "$result_string"
```

so I have created the bin directory with

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

and placed my script file inside there.
Then I have made it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/mein-befehl
```

After that I have exportet the path:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

Updating by

```
sudo ~/.bashrc
```

returns the following issue to me:

```
sudo: /home/martin/.bashrc: command not found
```

running

```
~/.profile
```

is accepted.

So when I restart the terminal and type

```
mein-befehl "2016"
```

returns a command not found issue.

**Question**: I have followed exactly the steps mentioned in the post. Other sources online point out similiar things. What can I still have done wrong?

my `$PATH` variable contains:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/martin/bin
```

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:~/bin` doesn't add to your `PATH` persistently **unless you add it to your `~/.bashrc` file**. Also, your `sudo ./bashrc` step should probably have been `source ~/.bashrc` or `. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: running 'source ~/.bashrc' made it. I have read somewhere in the linked post that running '~/.profile' should be enough. Can you explain the difference, please?

Comment: @steeldriver Enough for an answer, isn’t it?