# Install Portecle on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, java, certificates

Portecle is a nifty tool written in Java to manage keystores och certificates.

How to install it in Ubuntu?

At the time of writing there seems not to be a Ubuntu (deb) package. The zip download contains a **.desktop** file and suitable icons, but not instructions how to apply them.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did with Portecle version 1.11 and Ubuntu 18.04:

### Download and unpack

Download the zip from the [Sourceforge Portecle page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/portecle/).

Unpack the contents of a zip file on desired location, I prefer *opt*:

```
unzip portecle-1.11.zip
sudo mv portecle-1.11 /opt/
sudo ln -s /opt/portecle-1.11 /opt/portecle
```

### Make it executable

To run `.jar` file easily you need, besides the Java runtime, the `jarwrapper` package which can be installed like this:

```
sudo apt-get install jarwrapper
```

Set the permission to execute the jar file:

```
chmod +x /opt/portecle/portecle.jar
```

For easy access, add it to PATH. If you don't have a `~/bin` folder create it like this:

```
mkdir ~/bin
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add a line last in the `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

Re-read the file with:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

(The idea of this `~/bin` thing I borrowed from the [How can I create a custom terminal command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118312))

Create a link to portecle in the folder:

```
ln -s /opt/portecle/portecle.jar ~/bin/portecle
```

If done correctly, you can start it from a terminal simply with:

```
portecle
```

### Add to dash and launcher

To make Portecle searchable in the dash, link the icon and .desktop file to your profile:

```
ln -s /opt/portecle/icons/svg/portecle.svg ~/.local/share/icons/portecle.svg
ln -s /opt/portecle/net.sf.portecle.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/portecle.desktop
```

When started, you can right-click on its icon in the Ubuntu left panel (Launcher) and choose "Add to Favourites"/"Lock to Launcher" (depending on version).